# App-specific sound output devices

Tags: macos, itunes, audio, software-recommendation, music

I am looking for a control / app for sound output control which has function that allows me to have selective sound output for any app that plays sound or music.

Examples:

- I am playing music in iTunes and I want it use my AirPort Output for the sound. The rest of sound / voice / music from my MacBook can use the internal speak or headset to play it.
- At the same time, I can play my Spotify on my living room AirPort, my iTunes to my bedroom and watch YouTube on my MacBook.

Comment: Best I've ever been able to tell, the application has to request a separate audio output device.  The only app I've seen that can do it is VLC.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to do what you want with the Blackhole audio driver if you can stand a little tinkering: https://existential.audio/blackhole

A little more user friendly option is some of the commercial apps from Rogue Amoeba: https://rogueamoeba.com/ Check out Soundsource or Loopback. There is a try before you buy.

Comment: How would blackhole help? Could you give a little more information?